# Least amount of moves is required

Tags: optimization, checkerboard, board-games

You have 8x8 board and 9 identical pieces placed in a 3x3 square at the bottom left corner of the board. You are going to play a very simple game. Your task is to move these 9 pieces to the 3x3 square in the upper right corner of the board, with as few moves as possible. Two kinds of move are allowed:

1. You can move a piece one space up, down, left, or right, if the space it is moving to is empty.
2. You can "jump" a piece over another single piece next to it in one of those four directions, if the space on the other side is empty. You are allowed to make multiple jumps (as many as you like) with the same piece, as part of the same move.

For example here is a game of 30 moves:

[image: sample 30-move game]

I don't know the answer so I can't give you hints or ideas...

Anyways good luck!
BTW for the animation I used http://www.apronus.com/chess/diagram/editor/

Comment: Can the stones jump a series of stones in a line? (e.g. at the end of the animation could the last two moves be made to one move e6 to h6?)

Comment: As I understand you mean moving from e6 to h6  at one jump. It violates rule 2.  You can't jump over two stones. I guess I should write better.

Comment: I can't figure out what your rules mean. You're animation seems to jumping adjacent stones which is not allowed because an adjacent stone is an occupied space, violating rule 2. It also seems to be making diagonal moves which aren't specified by the rules. What kind of move was  b1 to d5? Also there was c1 to c5 which would be jumping over two stones which you said is not allowed.

Comment: b1 to d5 is b1-b3-b5-d5 which counts as one move;  and c1 to c5 is c1-c3-c5 also counts as one move.

Comment: @PédeLeão I believe that one move can perform multiple jumps, e.g. with stones at b1,b2,c3 and d4 you can move b1 to d5 (via b3 and d3).

Comment: on another note, how do you get that thing to make an animation?!

Comment: I think I see. Rule two doesn't forbid the two consecutive squares from being occupied; rather, the second square after an occupied square has to be unoccupied. Kind of like checkers.

Comment: it seems the movement rules are similar to those of checkers.

Comment: I've made some edits in the hope of clarifying the rules. nikamed, please say if I've got it wrong. Anyone, please feel free to edit further if anything's still unclear.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using a computer to attempt to beat my original solution I found some

> $22$ move games

Here is one:

> ```
> start
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
> 1 2 3 · · · · ·
> 4 5 6 · · · · ·
> 7 8 9 · · · · ·
>
> 1
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · 6 · · · · ·
> 1 2 3 · · · · ·
> 4 5 · · · · · ·
> 7 8 9 · · · · ·
>
> 2
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · 3 · · · · ·
> · · 6 · · · · ·
> 1 2 · · · · · ·
> 4 5 · · · · · ·
> 7 8 9 · · · · ·
>
> 3
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · · 3 · · · ·
> · · 6 · · · · ·
> 1 2 · · · · · ·
> 4 5 · · · · · ·
> 7 8 9 · · · · ·
>
> 4
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · · 3 1 · · ·
> · · 6 · · · · ·
> · 2 · · · · · ·
> 4 5 · · · · · ·
> 7 8 9 · · · · ·
>
> 5
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · · · 1 · · ·
> · · · 3 · · · ·
> · · 6 · · · · ·
> · 2 · · · · · ·
> 4 5 · · · · · ·
> 7 8 9 · · · · ·
>
> 6
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · · · 7 · · ·
> · · · · 1 · · ·
> · · · 3 · · · ·
> · · 6 · · · · ·
> · 2 · · · · · ·
> 4 5 · · · · · ·
> · 8 9 · · · · ·
>
> 7
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · · · · 7 · ·
> · · · · 1 · · ·
> · · · 3 · · · ·
> · · 6 · · · · ·
> · 2 · · · · · ·
> 4 5 · · · · · ·
> · 8 9 · · · · ·
>
> 8
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · · · · 7 9 ·
> · · · · 1 · · ·
> · · · 3 · · · ·
> · · 6 · · · · ·
> · 2 · · · · · ·
> 4 5 · · · · · ·
> · 8 · · · · · ·
>
> 9
> · · · · · 5 · ·
> · · · · · 7 9 ·
> · · · · 1 · · ·
> · · · 3 · · · ·
> · · 6 · · · · ·
> · 2 · · · · · ·
> 4 · · · · · · ·
> · 8 · · · · · ·
>
> 10
> · · · · · 5 · ·
> · · · · · 7 · 9
> · · · · 1 · · ·
> · · · 3 · · · ·
> · · 6 · · · · ·
> · 2 · · · · · ·
> 4 · · · · · · ·
> · 8 · · · · · ·
>
> 11
> · · · · · 5 · ·
> · · · · · 7 · 9
> · · · · 1 · · ·
> · · · 3 · · · ·
> · · 6 · · · · ·
> 4 2 · · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
> · 8 · · · · · ·
>
> 12
> · · · · · · 5 ·
> · · · · · 7 · 9
> · · · · 1 · · ·
> · · · 3 · · · ·
> · · 6 · · · · ·
> 4 2 · · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
> · 8 · · · · · ·
>
> 13
> · · · · · · 5 ·
> · · · · · 7 4 9
> · · · · 1 · · ·
> · · · 3 · · · ·
> · · 6 · · · · ·
> · 2 · · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
> · 8 · · · · · ·
>
> 14
> · · · · · · 5 ·
> · · · · · 7 4 9
> · · · · 1 · · ·
> · · · 3 · · · ·
> · · 6 · · · · ·
> · 2 · · · · · ·
> · 8 · · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
>
> 15
> · · · · · · 5 ·
> · · · · · 7 4 9
> · · · · 1 · · 8
> · · · 3 · · · ·
> · · 6 · · · · ·
> · 2 · · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
>
> 16
> · · · · · · 5 ·
> · · · · · 7 4 9
> · · · · 1 · · 8
> · · · 3 · · · ·
> · 2 6 · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
>
> 17
> · · · · · · 5 2
> · · · · · 7 4 9
> · · · · 1 · · 8
> · · · 3 · · · ·
> · · 6 · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
>
> 18
> · · · · · · 5 2
> · · · · · 7 4 9
> · · · · 1 · · 8
> · · · 3 · · · ·
> · · · 6 · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
>
> 19
> · · · · · 6 5 2
> · · · · · 7 4 9
> · · · · 1 · · 8
> · · · 3 · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
>
> 20
> · · · · · 6 5 2
> · · · · · 7 4 9
> · · · 3 1 · · 8
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
>
> 21
> · · · · · 6 5 2
> · · · · · 7 4 9
> · · · · 1 3 · 8
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
>
> 22
> · · · · · 6 5 2
> · · · · · 7 4 9
> · · · · · 3 1 8
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
> · · · · · · · ·
> ```

I reduced the search space by not allowing stones to moves to (although they can jump via) the spots marked with an * below:

```
* * * * · · · · 
* * * · · · · · 
* * · · · · · ·
* · · · · * * * 
· · · · * * * * 
1 2 3 * * * * * 
4 5 6 * * * * *
7 8 9 * * * * *
```

I then

> searched for states reachable within $13$ moves and then searched for the existence of an inversion* of a depth $13$ state in the states reachable in up to $10$ moves.
>
>  * rotate $180^\circ$ and reflect in the diagonal from bottom-left to top-right.

This yielded (not counting those that could be reflected into the blocked off space space):

> \begin{align}155\space&23\text{ move games}\\7\space&22\text{ move games}\end{align}

Of course

> There *could* be games that use the blocked off space with even less moves.

---

My original (human only) attempt:

> $24$
>
> ```
> start
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
> 1 2 3 · · · · · 
> 4 5 6 · · · · · 
> 7 8 9 · · · · · 
>
> 1
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · 3 · · · · · 
> 1 2 · · · · · · 
> 4 5 6 · · · · · 
> 7 8 9 · · · · · 
>
> 2
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · 9 · · · · · 
> · · 3 · · · · · 
> 1 2 · · · · · · 
> 4 5 6 · · · · · 
> 7 8 · · · · · · 
>
> 3
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · · 9 · · · · 
> · · 3 · · · · · 
> 1 2 · · · · · · 
> 4 5 6 · · · · · 
> 7 8 · · · · · · 
>
> 4
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · · 9 1 · · · 
> · · 3 · · · · · 
> · 2 · · · · · · 
> 4 5 6 · · · · · 
> 7 8 · · · · · · 
>
> 5
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · · · 1 · · · 
> · · · 9 · · · · 
> · · 3 · · · · · 
> · 2 · · · · · · 
> 4 5 6 · · · · · 
> 7 8 · · · · · · 
>
> 6
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · · · 7 · · · 
> · · · · 1 · · · 
> · · · 9 · · · · 
> · · 3 · · · · · 
> · 2 · · · · · · 
> 4 5 6 · · · · · 
> · 8 · · · · · · 
>
> 7
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · · · · 7 · · 
> · · · · 1 · · · 
> · · · 9 · · · · 
> · · 3 · · · · · 
> · 2 · · · · · · 
> 4 5 6 · · · · · 
> · 8 · · · · · · 
>
> 8
> · · · · · 5 · · 
> · · · · · 7 · · 
> · · · · 1 · · · 
> · · · 9 · · · · 
> · · 3 · · · · · 
> · 2 · · · · · · 
> 4 · 6 · · · · · 
> · 8 · · · · · · 
>
> 9
> · · · · · · 5 · 
> · · · · · 7 · · 
> · · · · 1 · · · 
> · · · 9 · · · · 
> · · 3 · · · · · 
> · 2 · · · · · · 
> 4 · 6 · · · · · 
> · 8 · · · · · · 
>
> 10
> · · · · · · 5 · 
> · · · · · 7 · · 
> · · · · 1 · · · 
> · · · 9 · · · · 
> · · 3 · · · · · 
> · 2 · · · · · · 
> 4 · 6 · · · · · 
> · · 8 · · · · · 
>
> 11
> · · · · · · 5 · 
> · · · · · 7 8 · 
> · · · · 1 · · · 
> · · · 9 · · · · 
> · · 3 · · · · · 
> · 2 · · · · · · 
> 4 · 6 · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
>
> 12
> · · · · · · 5 · 
> · · · · · 7 · · 
> · · · · 1 · 8 · 
> · · · 9 · · · · 
> · · 3 · · · · · 
> · 2 · · · · · · 
> 4 · 6 · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
>
> 13
> · · · · · · 5 · 
> · · · · · 7 · · 
> · · · · 1 · 8 · 
> · · · 9 · · · · 
> · · 3 · · · · · 
> · 2 6 · · · · · 
> 4 · · · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
>
> 14
> · · · · · · 5 · 
> · · · · · 7 6 · 
> · · · · 1 · 8 · 
> · · · 9 · · · · 
> · · 3 · · · · · 
> · 2 · · · · · · 
> 4 · · · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
>
> 15
> · · · · · · 5 · 
> · · · · · 7 · 6 
> · · · · 1 · 8 · 
> · · · 9 · · · · 
> · · 3 · · · · · 
> · 2 · · · · · · 
> 4 · · · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
>
> 16
> · · · · · · 5 · 
> · · · · · 7 · 6 
> · · · · 1 · 8 · 
> · · · 9 · · · · 
> · · 3 · · · · · 
> · 2 · · · · · · 
> · 4 · · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
>
> 17
> · · · · · · 5 4 
> · · · · · 7 · 6 
> · · · · 1 · 8 · 
> · · · 9 · · · · 
> · · 3 · · · · · 
> · 2 · · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
>
> 18
> · · · · · · 5 4 
> · · · · · 7 · 6 
> · · · · 1 · 8 · 
> · · · 9 · · · · 
> · 2 3 · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
>
> 19
> · · · · · 2 5 4 
> · · · · · 7 · 6 
> · · · · 1 · 8 · 
> · · · 9 · · · · 
> · · 3 · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
>
> 20
> · · · · · 2 5 4 
> · · · · · 7 · 6 
> · · · · 1 · 8 · 
> · · 3 9 · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
>
> 21
> · · · · · 2 5 4 
> · · · · · 7 3 6 
> · · · · 1 · 8 · 
> · · · 9 · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
>
> 22
> · · · · · 2 5 4 
> · · · · · 7 3 6 
> · · · 9 1 · 8 · 
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
>
> 23
> · · · · · 2 5 4 
> · · · · · 7 3 6 
> · · · · 1 · 8 9 
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
>
> 24
> · · · · · 2 5 4 
> · · · · · 7 3 6 
> · · · · · 1 8 9 
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · · 
> · · · · · · · ·
> ```

Comment: Nice. I'm curious if exist games with smaller than 24 moves.

Comment: For reasons of symmetry (even number of pieces, even number of XY locations), and reversibility (any valid move can be run in reverse), if N<24, then N =2*k where k <=11. So you would be looking for 22, 20, 18... moves.

Comment: @Penguino I think I agree it'll probably be even, but there are 9 stones, so maybe not?

Comment: Yes - my mistake. I meant "Assuming 9 is an even number...", which is patently false...

Comment: @nikamed, I have improved upon my solution using computer search